# jquery, toggle css content (arrow up and down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-class

I use jquery to toggle an element. the button that i use is styled with css.
I want to change the content, from `\25BC`(arrow down) to `\25B2` (arrow up), based on the state of the toggled element (`$(#categories ul)`).
How should it be done?

the code:

```
   a#categories-toggle:after{
      content: "\25BC";
   }

   $().ready(function(){
      $("#categories-toggle").on('click', function(eve){
         eve.preventDefault(); 
         $("#categories ul").toggle();
      });
   });
```

Comment: If you want to toggle the content, using CSS pseudo classes to add the content seems like one of the worst ideas  ever.

Comment: @adeneo why?! i want to toggle the content of the :AFTER

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS:

```
a#categories-toggle.down:after{
  content: "\25BC";
}
a#categories-toggle:after{
  content: "\25B2";
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="categories-toggle" href="#">foo</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#categories-toggle").on('click', function(eve){
     eve.preventDefault(); 
     $(this).toggleClass("down");
  });
```

Comment: toggle class 'down' surely?

Comment: And by the way, it looks like it's the class of the _link_ you want to toggle, not the UL. My answer is based on that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $('a#categories-toggle').css('content', '\25B2'); ?

Comment: You cannot select pseudo-elements with JS/JQ as they are not in the DOM

Comment: Aah, yeah. Stupid me. Removed the pseudo-stuff.

Comment: Your edited answer will not work either since the `content` is not a property of the anchor

Comment: This can be done(?), but i need it in the pseudo class.. it must be AFTER the content

Comment: @yossi You have to toggle a class (as in the answer given elsewhere).

Comment: Yeah, if you need the pseudo-stuff rather do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
a#categories-toggle.up:after{
      content: "\25BC";
   }
a#categories-toggle.down:after{
      content: "\25B2";
   }

 $().ready(function(){
      $("#categories-toggle").on('click', function(eve){
         eve.preventDefault(); 
         $("#categories ul").toggleClass(up down);
      });
   });
```

ToggleClass can switch between space seperated classes.